# If statement not returning correctly for the second part of calculation in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

> =iif(Fields!type.Value="Kilo",CDec(Fields!Pack.Value * Fields!Qty.Value * Fields!UnitPrice.Value),CDec(Fields!Qty.Value * Fields!UnitPrice.Value))

I am trying to calculate out the value by using If statement in SSRS.
In that if case statement, the first part is calculating correct. However the last part is giving #Error. Can anyone figure out what is not correct in here?

PS.the data type for "Pack" is string and the rest,"Qty" is int, and "UnitPrice" is decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the help but none of the expressions mentioned is working.The issue is data type of the Pack datatype. I am unable to convert into int type(apparently) even in SQL. And I resorted to get values from other column which is int or decimal data type.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression seems to be fine as there is no major difference between true and false statement..

Suggestion:-
Since data type for "Pack" is string.. we need to convert into decimal before CDec(Fields!Pack.Value)

```
=iif(Fields!type.Value="Kilo",
 CDec(CDec(Fields!Pack.Value) * Fields!Qty.Value * Fields!UnitPrice.Value)
 ,CDec(Fields!Qty.Value * Fields!UnitPrice.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Pack field to decimal before the math and remove the decimal conversion from the rest.  This should return decimal values for both output paths.  The additional convert is likely not needed.

```
=iif(Fields!type.Value="Kilo",
(CDecFields!Pack.Value) * Fields!Qty.Value * Fields!UnitPrice.Value,
Fields!Qty.Value * Fields!UnitPrice.Value)
```

However, if you really need to convert it to decimal afterward, wrap the whole iif statement in a conversion.  If it is just a question of presentation, wrap it in the format function.